# Xamarin android OpenGL. Загрузка Bitmap из ресурсов и конвертация в byte[]

Tags: android, c#, массивы, xamarin, bitmap

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь загрузить текстуру в OpenGL ES 3.0 и не как не получается... Мне необходимо из картинки получить массив byte[] в котором последовательно идут цвета пикселей( r g b a r g b a и т.д.). Размер должен быть [bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4]. Пытаюсь делать так:

```
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.floor_diffuse);
        int[] bufer = new int[bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height];
        bitmap.GetPixels(bufer, 0, bitmap.Width, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        byte[] diffuse = new byte[bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < bufer.Length; i++)
        {
            Color color = new Color(bufer[i]);
            diffuse[i * 4 + 0] = color.R;
            diffuse[i * 4 + 1] = color.G;
            diffuse[i * 4 + 2] = color.B;
            diffuse[i * 4 + 3] = color.A;
        }
```

Но это не работает. Почему-то после загрузки изображение имеет размер в 3 раза больше оригинала(4800*3894 против оригинала 1600*1298). Сам файл текстуры это .jpg файл. Когда тестировал не на Xamarin делал просто через LockBits и BitmapData, но в xamarin их нету.

Как мне получить мой массив цветов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему с загрузкой решил так, хотя почему bitmap изначально не того размера осталось для меня загадкой:

```
    public Bitmap LoadBitMapFromResource(int ResourceID)
    {
        var options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true, InPurgeable = true };
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Context.Resources, ResourceID, options);
        int width = options.OutWidth;
        int height = options.OutHeight;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Context.Resources, ResourceID);
        bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Сам массив цветов получаю так (Diffuse - загруженный Bitmap, DiffuseMap - массив цветов byte[]):

```
            int[] bufer = new int[Diffuse.Width * Diffuse.Height];
            Diffuse.GetPixels(bufer, 0, Diffuse.Width, 0, 0, Diffuse.Width, Diffuse.Height);

            DiffuseMap = new byte[Diffuse.Width * Diffuse.Height * 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < bufer.Length; i++)
            {
                Android.Graphics.Color color = new Android.Graphics.Color(bufer[i]);
                DiffuseMap[i * 4 + 0] = color.R;
                DiffuseMap[i * 4 + 1] = color.G;
                DiffuseMap[i * 4 + 2] = color.B;
                DiffuseMap[i * 4 + 3] = color.A;
            }
```

Comment: Можете считать заголовок , и проверить что это за информация. Возможно особенность методов, в коробке, очень интересный опыт

Answer (score 0):

Я давно не работал с Xamarin, ну там открытие stream(потоков) аналогично java.

Попробуйте так, в оф доках всё есть должно работать:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Context.Resources,Resource.Drawable.floor_diffuse);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то что мне нужно. Для изображения 1600x1298, например, я должен получить массив размером в 1600*1298*4 = 8'307'200 элементов (4 - rgba). В вашем же случае я получаю массив размером {byte[12'923'959]}. Там явно присутствует лишняя информация. Мне нужен чисто массив цветов